# Sort a Substring in Descending order using Vector, however getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, stl

I want to sort the string from N to M where N indicates the starting index and M indicates the ending index.

However, my code is getting failed with segmentation fault.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>  
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    string s;
    int M=0,N=0;

    cout<<"Enter String"<<endl;
    getline(cin,s);

    vector<char> data(s.begin(), s.end());

    cout<<"Enter start_index and end_index for sorting";
    cin>>N>>M;    //Passed externally as N=start_index, M=end_index

    std::sort(data.begin()+N, data.begin()+M, std::greater<char>());

    for (std::vector<char>::const_iterator i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: code is getting failed.

Comment: I don't see any sorting in your code.

Comment: `data.end() + M`?????

Comment: You meant `data.begin() + M)` instead, but that does not fix the code.

Comment: edited with sort function, sorry for the typing error which was earlier there with reverse.

Comment: Think about what you are asking for in `data.end()+M`.

Comment: Remember to check M and N against data.size()! After all it's an user input.

Comment: I tried it, worked for me. I only had to include <functional> to compile it (Visual Studio).

Comment: @FirstStep, did it fix the code.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b3a53f0b7344a68

here is the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example does work fine for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>  
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    string s = "ABCDEFG";
    int N = 1;
    int M = 5;

    vector<char> data(s.begin(), s.end());

    std::sort(data.begin() + N, data.begin() + M, std::greater<char>());

    for (auto& character : data)
        std::cout << character << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

**http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee7c5f05afe85115**

I suspect you get an empty string with cin, and therefore your data.begin() is invalid. 
Be cautious with user entered data. Always do proper checking for input that may break your code.

Additonally your templated greater is the comparing function for the wrong type.

Comment: my string is not empty string, still it is not working for me.
Indicating runtime error.

Comment: This MCVE works just fine, look for the errors in the differences to your code and do proper input checking.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b3a53f0b7344a68

@Trevir, pls help me out in finding why the segmentation fault.

Comment: Thnx buddy for pointing out the segmentation fault. (@Trevir)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the above question is from the guidance of Trevir.
  In order to avoid the segmentation fault, check the size of the input 
  string and then apply operations on it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>  
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    string s;
    int M,N;

    cout<<"Enter String"<<endl;
    getline(cin,s);

    if ( s.size() == 0 )
    {
       std::cout << "Empty Input" << std::endl;   
       return 0;
    }

    vector<char> data(s.begin(), s.end());

    cout<<"Enter start_index and end_index for sorting";
    cin>>N>>M;    //Passed externally as N=start_index, M=end_index

    std::sort(data.begin()+N, data.begin()+M, std::greater<char>());

    for (std::vector<char>::const_iterator i = data.begin(); i != data.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i;

    return 0;
}
```